# Securely transfer data from Facebook JavaScript SDK method FB.login to my server-side code

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using JavaScript SDK `FB.login` method I get user details in client JS code. I'd like to transfer this data to my server-side script. The first idea is a plain AJAX call. The problem is that I can't verify from the server side that this data comes from authority (my JS that performs Facebook login) and not from someone that abuses my AJAX endpoint.

P.S. I've found this solution: [FB.login with PHP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008694/fb-login-with-php-api/6533055#6533055)
(only access token is transfered and PHP SDK is used on the server)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  I can't tell if you're asking a question about client access to FB or server access to FB or hiding server endpoint when client talks to server?  I would suggest revising your question.  Make the very first sentence by your question and make it clear what you're asking.  You can add explanatory detail in further paragraphs.

Comment: I've completely rewrited the question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is for your server to just get the data from FB directly.  You may have to involve the user to gain access, but if the server is getting the data from FB directly, then there's no endpoint for people to abuse.

If you're going to get the data from FB in the client and then pass it to the server, then you'll have to use authenticated connections into the server and you'll have to use some form of authentication you trust where if anyone is found abusing the endpoint, you can immediately cut off their access and expunge their data.  That's why lots of services use developer keys as a means of authenticating people into the endpoints.  I don't personally know of any way that you could actually guarantee that the client is giving you good data.

Comment: What about the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008694/fb-login-with-php-api/6533055#6533055 it seems to use access_token transfered from JS to server code?

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is the following -- I can change in JS that user is already logged into Facebook and my app. If found that he\she is logged I'd like to fire my own auth server side.