# How can facebook php sdk get the access token from javascript sdk?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

FacebookI am using facebook javascript sdk to loigin a user, and then I wish to get some of his info via the php sdk, but I keep getting "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

this is the relevant html/js code:

```
     <script>


 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '8',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//url/frontend/channel.php', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,
      oauth:true,
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
      submitform();
}     });
  };

  function submitform() {

    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', function(response) {
      //submits a form from this page...
    });

  }
</script>
       <a href="javascript:FB.login()" class="facebook-login">Facebook</a>
```

and the php that fails is :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(               
                        'appId'  => Configuration::$facebook_app_id,
                          'secret' => Configuration::$facebook_app_secret));
            // Get User ID

             $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,id','GET');
```

It seemed to work for a while, and then it breaks with

```
"   [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
                   [type] => OAuthException
                   [code] => 2500",
```

Anyone has an idea how to stabilize this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that happens because your acces token was expired?
There are several access token types. And if your access token is a "short-term token" - you must refresh it.
you can read abot acces tokens here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
In python server lib for facebook i used method fetchToken(appId, secret) to refresh my expired token.

Comment: but shouldn't the access token  be refreshed by the javascript FB.login() and then passed to the php ? the php code is called from the form immediately after the js code.

Comment: I look into source php fb lib. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php
Just look there for "accessToken"
FB looks into signed_request request parameter or cookie with name fbsr_'.$this->getAppId()
try to debug for cookies
maybe fb javascript api updates cookie after calling your callback for "auth.authResponseChange" And your server got old cookie with old accessToken

Comment: Oh, just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008694/fb-login-with-php-api
Maybe you should try make fb auth another way